# How do you deserialze a varbinary in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I followed [this guide](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/292/configuring-sql-server-for-session-state-in-asp-net-core-1-0-mvc) to store my session data in a sql server table.

How do I deseriazle the value that is stored? The sql data type is a varbinary.

I have tried this, but I get this error on the deserialize line: *"The input stream is not a valid binary format"*

```
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

byte[] byteVal = _context.Sessions.First().Value;
System.IO.Stream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteVal);
var des = formatter.Deserialize(stream);
```

Comment: Why are you trying to serialize the object if you're storing it as `varbinary`? You should be able to store & retrieve it in SQL directly using a `byte[]`

Comment: I'm not trying to serialize anything. I want to deserialize the varbinary value. @CamBruce

Comment: Sorry, I missread. Unless you're not including it, in your snippet, shouldn't you be Serializing `byteVal` or `Sessions.First()` directly?

Comment: Sorry, a little confused. What would I serialize it as? Isn't it already serialized?  @CamBruce

Comment: Shouldn't the Session object automatically handle the serialization & deserialization for you?

Answer (score 0):

The following of code retrieves your value and places it in a byte array called byteVal:

```
byte[] byteVal = _context.Sessions.First().Value;
```

I personally prefer to name such a byte arrays `bytes` rather than byteVal just to make it more clear that it's muliple bytes long.

```
byte[] bytes = _context.Sessions.First().Value;
```

Anyway, at this point you can use `bytes` with any method that accepts a byte array.  (like session storage)

So no serialization or serialization is necessary.

Comment: Thanks. If I do
string x = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
I can see some readable data (\u0002\0\0\u0002?6'?#+?????\nm?\u007f?\0\u0006random\0\0\0\u0003abc\)
Any Idea why? @RonC

Comment: Sure,  in such a case you are asking to have the byte array interpreted as an ascii string, so you are seeing what it would look like if it were an ascii string.  But it's not an ascii string so it's best not to do that.  If you want to see it like a string it's better to use Convert.ToBase64String(bytes); given that all byte arrays can validly be converted to a base64 string.  This is referred to as "base 64 encoding the byte array".  In such a case you can go the opposite way from a base64 string to bytes by doing this byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);

Comment: sorry for the late response. Even more gibberish when I do Covnert.ToBase64String(bytes) unfortunately.

Comment: Sure, it will look like gibberish, but it's one industry standard way to encode a byte array as a string.  And it's reversible.    Alternatively if you want to see the bytes as hex you there are lots of different ways to do that.  The simplest is probably string hexString = BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-","");

Comment: @johnluke.laue please remember to accept my answer if it solved your problem.